# How do I wire a new ceiling light with 2 red wires?

Tags: wiring, lighting

I bought a new ceiling light, but the wires are complicated.
It has 2 red wires and one green ground wire. There are 2 white wires too but they are connected by themselves.
My ceiling has 1 black wire , 1 white wire , 1 ground wire. Do the wires work with only the matching color ports?
Can I connect the 2 red wires from the ceiling light fixture to the black wire from the ceiling, but leave the white wire out?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A picture or diagram would really help here.

Comment: Where are you located?